# Exporting routes in Koa

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa-router, koa2

I'm having a strange issue when exporting my routes. For some reason, this code works for me:

**app.js**

```
import Koa from 'koa'
import routes from './routes/index'

const app = new Koa()

app.use(routes)

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening at http://localhost:3000')
})

export default app
```

**routes/index.js**

```
import Router from 'koa-router'
const router = new Router()

router.get('/', async ctx => {
  await ctx.render('index')
})

export default router.routes()
```

---

but when I just export the routes function and then try to call it in `app.js`, I get an error:

**app.js**

```
import Koa from 'koa'
import routes from './routes/index'

const app = new Koa()

app.use(routes())

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening at http://localhost:3000')
})

export default app
```

**routes/index.js**

```
import Router from 'koa-router'
const router = new Router()

router.get('/', async ctx => {
  await ctx.render('index')
})

export default router.routes
```

Why doesn't it work when I do it the second way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably would like to export a [bound function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Creating_a_bound_function), so `this` inside it would refer to a router object.

It could be done nicely with a [bind operator](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind). I believe it's already available since you are using `async/await`.

```
import Router from 'koa-router'
const router = new Router()

router.get('/', async ctx => {
  await ctx.render('index')
})

export default ::router.routes
```

Comment: Ah, I see, I had to do `export default router.routes.bind(router)`. And I didn't know about the bind operator as a shorthand for that, thanks a lot for sharing! I hope it makes it into the spec.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a method:

```
router.allowedMethods()
```

like this:

```
app.use(router.routes(), router.allowedMethods())
```